# Chrome con el autorellenado, cambia el valor de un formulario

Tags: php, chrome

Estoy mostrando un formulario para mantenimiento de datos y, por lo menos en un campo, llego a ver durante instantes e, valor que publico, pero, automaticamente Chrome lo machaca con otro valor. En la imagen que comparto, se puede ver que indico un value, para un campo, pero en pantalla aparece otro

El formulario se ve asi: http://imtp.me/f05202sab.p

Este es el codigo del formulario, y da lo mismo lo que ponga en autocomplete

```
<form action="<?=$_REQUEST['url'];?>"  onsubmit="return validaUsuario(this)" autocomplete="aaaa" method="POST">


            <input type="hidden" value="<?= $request->getAttribute('delete')?>" name="delete"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario_id">Id</label> <input type="number"
                    value="<?= $datos->getUsuario_id()?>" name="usuario_id"  class="form-control"
                    readonly="readonly" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario_nombre">Nombre</label> <input type="text"
                    value="<?= $datos->getUsuario_nombre()?>" name="usuario_nombre" required  class="form-control"
                    <?= $read ?> />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario_apellidos">Apellido</label> <input type="text"
                    value="<?= $datos->getUsuario_apellidos()?>" name="usuario_apellidos" <?= $read ?>  class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <?php var_dump($datos);?>
                <label for="usuario_correo">Correo Electónico</label> <input type="mail"
                    value="<?= $datos->getUsuario_correo()?>" name="usuario_correo" <?= $read ?> required  class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="usuario_password">Contraseña</label> <input type="text"
                    value="<?= $datos->getUsuario_password()?>" name="usuario_password" <?= $read ?> required  class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type=submit value="<?=$_REQUEST['opcion'];?>" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

y para simplificar una vista del fuente que recibe el navegador http://imtp.me/f05402sab.p

Solo funciona mal en Chrome; tanto en Firefox como en IE (Eclipse) se ve bien. ¿Sabeis como solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola, debes poner el código HTML de tu formulario y todo lo que sea necesario para poder ayudarte. No se deben incluir códigos como capturas de imágenes.

Comment: No pasé código, porque no tengo claro que sea un problema de código, ya que en HTML aparece el campo con el "value" correcto y solo es cuando presenta Chrome el formulario, que ese valor desaparece y pone otro valor que debe sacar del autorellenado.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar que el navegador rellene campos debes usar `autocomplete="none"` en cada campo.
Por ejemplo:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" >
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="none"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

En el ejemplo anterior se esta evitando que el navegador rellene automáticamente con un email previamente almacenado. Saludos!

[Documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)

Comment: Lo he probado a nivel de form y no va, a nivel de campo, no lo he probado, pero....estoy haciendo mantenimiento de ficheros, eso hace que, para ser correcto, debería dejar el autocompletado on en las altas, y off en las modificaciones, y campo a campo....¿no hay otra opcion?

Comment: debes usar `autocomplete="none"` en cada campo que desees evitar el autocompletado. Si lo haces en la etiqueta del form, no va a funcionar correctamente. Saludos!

Comment: En mi caso, no funciona. Lo que no entiendo es porque funcina en Firefox o en los navegadores de Eclipse, pero no en Chrome